# Android service stops after less than 5 minutes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I am creating an Android application that needs to constantly send UDP packets to a server.

The problem is that after 2-5 minutes, after the screen is off, the service stops sending data, until I turn the screen back on (can also confirm on the server side).

Here is the service start command:

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service.class));
```

The onStartCommand:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Armed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    (new Thread(new App())).start();
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

And the run method, from the App thread:

```
public void run(){
    Vibrator alarm = (Vibrator) MainActivity.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    String IP = getWiFiIP(MainActivity.getAppContext());

    while(true){
        while (IP.equals(wifiAddr)){ //Confirm presence on local network, with host
            //Unlocked door
            System.out.println("Started locally!");
            sendData(KEY, hostAddrLocal);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            IP = getWiFiIP(MainActivity.getAppContext());
        }
   }
}
```

I am positive that I am not running out of memory, I have no other applications up, running on Galaxy S4, with Lollipop 5.0

Is it because I am interacting with the main activity, to get the context
`MainActivity.getAppContext()` ?

I tried many things, including `STICKY_SERVICE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that after 2-5 minutes, after the screen is off, the service stops sending data, until I turn the screen back on (can also confirm on the server side).

The CPU has powered down, as has the WiFi radio, in all likelihood. You would need to acquire a `WakeLock` and a `WifiLock` to keep both powered on. For ordinary users with ordinary hardware, keeping the CPU and WiFi radio on all the time will be *very* unpopular due to battery drain.

Comment: Oh ok, I see, I thought that by creating a service, instead of a thread will be sufficient to keep the service running in the background at all times. Cheers!

Comment: @WilhelmSorban: The service is running, insofar as your process is probably still around. The CPU is not. The CPU powering down is (very) roughly equivalent to a Windows PC going into suspend mode -- programs are still in RAM, but nothing runs. Though do bear in mind that processes with services can still be terminated to free up memory for other processes. Using a foreground service (`startForeground()`) can help with that, but nothing can keep a process around forever.

Comment: Is there a way to make the service wake up the CPU/WiFi, send the packet, then put it back to sleep? (I think there should be, as I believe this is how email and other notifications work?) If so, can you point me some good sources? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @WilhelmSorban: You can use `AlarmManager` with an `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` alarm. However, you seem to be trying to do this every five seconds, and so `AlarmManager` may not help much with power drain from the CPU. In fact, it's possible that it might make things worse. Plus, you would still need the `WifiLock`. Apps that need continuous connections to a server need to be able to gracefully degrade to a mobile data connection, then aggressively cut back any "heartbeat" packets, in order to get good results from a power standpoint.

Comment: @WilhelmSorban: "I think there should be, as I believe this is how email and other notifications work?" -- no, they will [use GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), in general, rather than rolling their own mechanism. Or, they will have a socket open on *mobile data* (not WiFi), in which case an *inbound* packet can wake up the device. AFAIK, that's the approach taken by third-party SIP clients (e.g., CSipSimple).

Answer (score 2):

Android is programmed to fall asleep after inactivity.  When that happens, it powers down the processor and doesn't allow any app to process.  To be an exception to this rule, you need to hold a partial wakelock.  Doing so will cause you to use more battery though so try not to hold it longer than needed.